# Java HashMap MAXIMUM_CAPACITY

Tags: java, hashmap, bit-manipulation

I am going through the `java.util.HashMap` class code and found that `MAXIMUM_CAPACITY` is defined as follows:

```
static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
```

Is there any specific reason to initialize like that instead of assigning direct value?

Comment: The coder didn't want to remember how hexadecimal numbers work? Apart from that, I cannot find any other reason.

Comment: Other than this being easier to read than some random decimal/hex value I don't see a reason for doing it like this.

Comment: Visually, it's easier to tell what `1 << 30` is than 0x4000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 << 30` is the largest power of 2 that can be stored as positive value in a signed 32-bit integer. Presumably it's that what the author wanted to express. This feature us much harder to see from the alternative 0x4000000 or even a decimal representation.

The javadoc comment basically says this already:

```java
/**
 * The maximum capacity, used if a higher value is implicitly specified
 * by either of the constructors with arguments.
 * MUST be a power of two <= 1<<30.
 */
static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it explains how the value was chosen - 2^30 (which is a power of 2, about half the maximum int value) is more meaningful than something like 0x40000000 or 1073741824.
Second, the compiler calculates the value anyway.